# Accurev - How to update the file content in a stream after a promote

Tags: accurev

We have different streams for different environments. It is a grail project. So there is a property file called application.properties which has a property called app.version. I want that to be updated automatically post every promote done on the stream. Each stream will have different version number. Trigger server_post_promote_trig will be used to handle the post promote operation, but I am not sure how to access the files in the stream through script. I tried to give the path as /Folder1/file as reflected in the xml trigger input file, but I cannot update the file as trigger perl file complains it cannot find the file.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly.  You want to increment the version in a file under source control when ever a promotion occurs in the stream.  If this is correct, you need to create a workspace off said stream which will edit/keep/promote the new version of this file.  I would create a separate script that gets called by the server_post_promote trigger whenever a promotion occurs in this stream.  This script would be placed under src control which is accessible in the workspace you created above.

Answer (score 1):

In Accurev, files can only be modified via a workspace. As this is the case It may be better to implement a pre promote trigger to update this version information in the file when the user is performing the workspace to stream promote.

This would be similar to the existing `Addheader` script that can be found in the examples directory on the `accurev` server.

Answer (score 0):

Also, within the script, you will probably want to build in logic to detect the promotion of the version file, to block updating the file again.